# How can i find out what module is running on each port?

Tags: linux

I want to find out what is running on COM port (tty0). I tried `dmesg | grep tty0` but it didn't show me anything about tty0 port. How can I get this information? Thanks

Comment: `tty0` is not a COM port; it refers to the current virtual console. COM ports start with `ttyS`, e.g. `ttyS0`.

Comment: Also, could you clarify what you mean by "what module is running"? What exactly is a module here?

Comment: It is a Zigbee module, for wireless communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that by "COM port" (which is Windows-specific terminology) you mean serial port, it is in fact ttyS0.

If you want to find what's on the first virtual console, tty0, you can do a `ps -e | grep tty0`.  To find out what's using the serial port, `fuser /dev/ttyS0` will give the pids of any relevant processes.

Comment: yes, I meant ttyS0. `fuser /dev/ttyS0` doesn't show me anything, nor does `lsof /dev/ttyS0`. Actually, I've now entered `dmesg |grep ttyS0` and I've gotten this: `[    1.282940] serial8250: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a NS16550A`. I don't understand the output, how can I find out the module running on COM port from this output?

Comment: The problem is solved, I managed to find out what is running on ttyS0 port by running those 2 command. I don't know why it didn't work yesterday. Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `lsof`. For all the devices, you can also run

```
lsof /dev
```